# How to remove rows that have only 1 combination for a given ID

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C")
Measurement <- c ("Length","Breadth","Breadth","Breadth","Length","Length","Length")  
Value <- c(4.5,6.6,7.5,3.3,5.6,8.9,16.1)
df <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,Value)
df

  ID Measurement Value
1  A      Length   4.5
2  A     Breadth   6.6
3  A     Breadth   7.5
4  B     Breadth   3.3
5  B      Length   5.6
6  C      Length   8.9
7  C      Length  16.1
```

My desired output is

```
  ID Measurement Value
1  A      Length   4.5
2  A     Breadth   6.6
3  A     Breadth   7.5
4  B     Breadth   3.3
5  B      Length   5.6
```

I want to remove rows that have only 1 combination for a given ID.

I do something like this to remove rows in a dataframe that has only 1 column with 1 unique value.

```
df_count <- length(unique(df$Measurement))
    if(df_count < 2)
      next
```

I am trying to extend that to use in a data frame that has a combination of 2 columns and I am not able to use the same logic. Please help with some inputs on how to solve this

Comment: Could try `df[df$ID %in% names(which(table(unique(df[-3])$ID) > 1)), ]` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dplyr, it would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(Measurement) > 1)
##       ID Measurement Value
##   <fctr>      <fctr> <dbl>
## 1      A      Length   4.5
## 2      A     Breadth   6.6
## 3      A     Breadth   7.5
## 4      B     Breadth   3.3
## 5      B      Length   5.6
```

Answer (score 4):

Base R: Give a logical value created by `ave` to the `i` parameter of `"["`:

```
 df[ ave( as.character(df$Measurement), df$ID, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)) ) > 1, ]
  ID Measurement Value
1  A      Length   4.5
2  A     Breadth   6.6
3  A     Breadth   7.5
4  B     Breadth   3.3
5  B      Length   5.6
```

This is a case where I think the base solution is "dominated" in terms of easy of programming and intelligibility by both the data.table and the dplyr solutions offered. That is not often the case in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, Count := length(unique(Measurement)), ID][Count > 1]
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, a much better one-liner suggested by @DavidArenburg:

```
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(Measurement) > 1) .SD, by = ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `anyDuplicated`

```
df[with(df, ave(as.character(Measurement), ID, FUN = anyDuplicated)!=0),]
```