# Remove both pairs of a duplicated case

Tags: r, distinct

I have a data set with some ambiguous end dates. Since I cannot decide which one is correct I would like to remove them from the data frame, but cannot figure out the way.

Here is a sample df:

```
ID = as.integer(c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6))
Feature = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C")
From = as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2016-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01"))
To = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", NA, "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2016-01-01","2016-01-01"))
df = data.frame(ID, Feature, From, To)


#which looks like this:

   ID Feature       From         To
1   1       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
2   1       A 2015-01-01       <NA>
3   2       A 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
4   2       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
5   2       A 2015-01-01 2017-01-01
6   3       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
7   3       B 2015-01-01 2017-01-01
8   4       B 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
9   5       B 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
10  5       B 2016-01-01 2017-01-01
11  6       B 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
12  6       C 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
```

I would like to remove all ambigous cases that are duplicated on each variable except for the last one (ID 1 and 2 are such cases). Any other variance or duplicity is tolerated in the data set.

> EDIT: Perhaps, I should specify that the Feature variable means a
>   certain disadvantage on the labour market (such as being disabled,
>   lone parent, young graduate with no work experience, etc). So one
>   person can have multiple disadvantages and these can occur in multiple
>   times. I edited the original sample df to allow for such variance.

My ideal sample df would keep these cases:

```
   ID Feature       From         To
6   3       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
7   3       B 2015-01-01 2017-01-01
8   4       B 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
9   5       B 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
10  5       B 2016-01-01 2017-01-01
11  6       B 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
12  6       C 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
```

I have been trying to look at other SO questions on duplicated and distinct functions, but could not find a similar post. I think my problem is different than the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232998/how-to-remove-rows-that-have-only-1-combination-for-a-given-id) post, because I do not care about the number of cases (features) retained in my data set, as long as their dates do not contradict. By condradiction I mean that a feature was identified twice, has the same starting date, but **different end dates**. In those cases, I do not know which one to select, so I prefer to remove them entirely.

I have been also playing around with the functions, e.g. like this:

```
select = !duplicated(df[,1:3])
df[select,]
```

but cannot find a way how to remove both pairs of a duplicated case, and not just the second one. 
Thank you in advance for any tips!

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates and all elements which have duplicates, one solution could be to create a `filter_cases` `data.frame` containing the duplicates. Then, you use this `filter_cases` to keep only the elements in your `original` `data.frame` that are **not** in the `filter_cases` `data.frame`

Comment: With `data.table` you can do `DT[!DT[duplicated(DT)], on=names(DT)]` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/49408559/5414452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve removal of all instances of duplicated rows is to reverse the order of the variable for the `duplicated` function, which always:

> returns the index i of the first duplicated entry x[i]

Using this functionality, we can then combine the forward and reverse passes to remove all rows which contain duplicated data.

```
# first pass
s1 = !duplicated(df[,1:3])
# second pass on the data.frame with reversed order in each column
s2 = !duplicated(apply(df[,1:3], 2, rev))
# the second pass needs to be back-reversed to match the original df
df[s1 & rev(s2), ]
   ID Feature       From         To
 5  3       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
 6  3       B 2015-01-01 2017-01-01
```

Or we can use a more elegant solution that @dalloliogm pointed out, and apply `duplicated` with argument `fromLast = TRUE`.

```
s2 = !duplicated(df[,1:3], fromLast = TRUE)
df[s1 & s2, ]
```

Comment: you can use the fromLast option in duplicated instead of using apply and rev.

Comment: the `df [s1 & s2,]` suggestion is elegant and works wonderfully even if a case has more than one ambiguous duplicate. Thank you both answerers for pointing out this creative use of `fromLast` argument.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to remove all ambigous cases that are duplicated on each
>   variable, except for the last one (ID 1 and 2), but retain any other
>   type of variance, e.g if the ID has more than one feature (ID 3).

It would be a bit easier to answer you if you could make a longer example. It is not clear to me

First, identify which rows have more "variability", e.g. more than one feature per ID:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(n_features=n_distinct(Feature))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Feature       From         To n_features
  <int>  <fctr>     <date>     <date>      <int>
1     1       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01          1
2     1       A 2015-01-01         NA          1
3     2       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01          1
4     2       A 2015-01-01 2017-01-01          1
5     3       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01          2
6     3       B 2015-01-01 2017-01-01          2
```

Second, remove all the duplicated rows, except those with "variability":

```
> df %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(n_features=n_distinct(Feature)) %>% 
       ungroup %>% 
       filter(
               (!duplicated(Feature, From, To) | !duplicated(Feature, From, To, fromLast=T))| n_features>1)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     ID Feature       From         To n_features
  <int>  <fctr>     <date>     <date>      <int>
1     3       A 2015-01-01 2016-01-01          2
2     3       B 2015-01-01 2017-01-01          2
```